# React: Problem in dynamic nested routing. How to solve this error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am getting the following error while trying to implement dynamic routing in React JS.
[image]

The required files are:

Assignment.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Users from './containers/Users/Users';
import Courses from './containers/Courses/Courses';
import {Route, Link, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import Course from './containers/Course/Course';

class Assignment extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to ="/Users"> Users </Link></li>
                    <li><Link to ="/Courses"> Courses </Link></li>
                </ul>
             <Switch>
             <Route path ="/Users" component = {Users}/>
             <Route path ="/Courses" exact component = {Courses}/>  
             </Switch>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default Assignment;
```

Courses.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Link, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import './Courses.css';
import Course from '../Course/Course';
class Courses extends Component {
    state = {
        courses: [
            { id: 1, title: 'Angular - The Complete Guide' },
            { id: 2, title: 'Vue - The Complete Guide' },
            { id: 3, title: 'PWA - The Complete Guide' }
        ]
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Amazing Udemy Courses</h1>
                <section className="Courses">
                    {
                        this.state.courses.map( course => {
                            return (<Link key ={course.id} to = {this.props.match.url + '/' + course.id + '/' + course.title}>
                            <Course className = "Course" name = {course.title} no = {course.id} />
                            </Link>);
                        } )
                    }
                    <Route path = "/Courses/:id/:name" exact component = {Course} />
                </section>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Courses;
```

Course.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Course extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.props.match.params.name}</h1>
                <p>{this.props.match.params.id}_</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Course;
```

Why am I getting this error? Can anyone fix this? I am also finding it difficult to following dynamic routing.
PS. I am getting the error at /Courses url only not at the base url.

Comment: Have you tried passing props.match.params from Courses to Course?

Comment: in Courses component you're not initializating state in your constructor
you also need to declare your props in the constructor

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {...}
}

Comment: I think you can also wrap Course with [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter).

Comment: @Abdel P. the syntax they are using for the state is fine in newer versions.

Comment: I didn't know about that, thanks @LindaPaiste

Comment: @Abdel P. I was going to send you a docs link, but I can't find it mentioned in the React docs (I don't know if there's a specific name for it?).  It's a result of [es6 class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) which can be supported with [this babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) for older JS versions.  Here's [two](https://daveceddia.com/where-initialize-state-react/) [articles](https://blog.g2i.co/react-class-components-with-es6-and-class-fields-927b2b59f94e) about using class properties to initialize component state.

Answer (score 0):

### Problems

The props such as `params` are only passed down to the top-level component which is rendered by a `Route`.  When you are rendering the list of individual `Course` components inside your `Course` component, the `Courses` gets `this.props.params` but each `Course` does not.  You can pass them down manually:

```
<Course {...this.props} className="Course" name={course.title} no={course.id} />
```

The above passes all props, while the below passes just the params prop.

```
<Course params={this.props.params} className="Course" name={course.title} no={course.id} />
```

This resolves your error, but it is not at all doing what you want it to be doing.  The `match` is for the **current** URL, so `this.props.match.params.name` and `this.props.match.params.id` are both empty values when we are on the `/Courses` page.  Meanwhile, the props `className`, `name`, and `no` which you set on the `Course` are all unused.

Additionally, the `Route` to `"/Courses/:id/:name"` which you have put inside of `Courses` should really be on the top level of the app alongside the main `"/Courses"` `Route`.  Ideally it should be listed **before** the courses homepage route because you want to match to more specific paths before broader ones, but it won't present any conflicts with `exact` either way.

There is a lot wrong here and I recommend that you read up on the fundamentals of react-router and writing reusable components.

### Rewrites

You are trying to use the same component to render a course for both your `Route` `"/Courses/:id/:name"` and as a list item on the `Courses` page, but one needs to have its data passed directly as props while the other gets its data from `this.props.match.params`.  In order to solve this, we will make a component that handles just the rendering of the course.  It gets its information from props, and is agnostic to where those props come from.  This means we can use this component on any page of your app as long as we pass it a `name` and `no`.  I used a function component, but it doesn't matter.

```
const CourseListItem = ({ name, no }) => {
  return (
    <div className="course">
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <p>Course #{no}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

We can't send our `Route` directly to this component, because it wouldn't know the `name` and `no`.  So we use an intermediate component that is responsible for setting the props of `CourseListItem` based on the router props (`this.props.match.params`).  You could of course render other HTML or components and not just `CourseListItem`.  I used a `class` for consistency with what you had before, but again it doesn't matter.

```
class SingleCoursePage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <CourseListItem
        name={this.props.match.params.name}
        no={this.props.match.params.id}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

In our `Courses` component, we loop through the courses from `this.state` and for each course we render the `CourseListItem`, setting the props `name` and `no` from the `course` object.  See how we can use same component in different ways?  If you wanted, you could make `className` be a prop of `CourseListItem` so that you could style it differently in different places.

```
class Courses extends Component {
  state = {
    courses: [
      { id: 1, title: "Angular - The Complete Guide" },
      { id: 2, title: "Vue - The Complete Guide" },
      { id: 3, title: "PWA - The Complete Guide" }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Amazing Udemy Courses</h1>
        <section className="Courses">
          {this.state.courses.map((course) => {
            return (
              <Link
                key={course.id}
                to={"/Courses/" + course.id + "/" + course.title}
              >
                <CourseListItem name={course.title} no={course.id} />
              </Link>
            );
          })}
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As I explained, we are moving that `Route` for the single course page up to the top-level component, alongside the other routes.

```
class Assignment extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/Users">Users</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/Courses">Courses</Link></li>
          </ul>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/Users" component={Users} />
            <Route path="/Courses/:id/:name" component={SingleCoursePage} />
            <Route path="/Courses" exact component={Courses} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-64732017-g7zry?file=/src/App.js) -  There's no CSS styling but all of the routing works!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried withRouter?

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
console.log(props.match.params);
```

then export the component like:

```
export default withRouter(TestComponent);
```